# How quickly identify duplicate numbers in the list with dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a little question about searching same numbers.

**What I have:**

I have a list with dictionaries. In this dictionaries there are 2 pairs key-val, one is unique id and other is list with numbers.

**What I need to do:**

I need to define **if there is any same number in other lists in other dicts** and write `parent` id and this same number in the `processed_data` dictionary. But I have very large `all` list and this processing will take around 3.6 days.

**So here is a question**

I want to find any other methods to process it faster, for about 12 hours if possible and would be thankful for any help.

PS (Maybe some multiprocessing or threading will help somehow, but I got big doubts about if it is possible)

(Let's omit here situations when it iter the same dict & its list and find same number)

```
# List with dictionaries:
all = [
       {'id' : 0, 'numbers' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
       {'id' : 1, 'numbers' : [5, 7, 9]},
       {'id' : 2, 'numbers' : [10, 12, 14]},
       {'id' : 3, 'numbers' : [3, 12, 5]}
]

# Here I will store the results
processed_data = {}

# For every row
for every in all:

    id = every['id']
    numbers_list = every['numbers']

    for every_2 in all:
        numbers_list_2 = every_2['numbers']

        # If number exists in the other row
        # I remember id of the list which contains this number
        # And number
        for number in numbers_list_2:
            if number in numbers_list:
                processed_data[id] = number

print(processed_data)
```

Expected output:

```
{0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 12, 3: 5}
```

Comment: What about `3:12`, you are loosing it.

Comment: @Adirio yes, I didn't expect to loose sth, but question is the same. I am looking for other more efficient way to process data

Comment: I am confused by your output. For the number 5 you have listed the ids 0, 1, 3 which is fine, but for the number 12 you  have listed only the id 2 even though 12 appears in id 3 as well. whats your expected output really meant to look like for this sample dataset

Comment: Also, can we change the `all` type? You currently are using a list of dicts with two keys, id and numbers. Could we use a dict where the keys are the 'id'  and the values are the 'numbers'. That will also increase the performance. `all = { 0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1: [5, 7, 9], ... }`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle yes, please, see my comment above

Comment: @Adirio no, we cannot, because actually id is NOT unique

Comment: if id is not unique then your output should not be a dict using the id since dict keys must be unique

Comment: And what if we merge the entries with the same id? If they are not unique and they contain no further info we cna merge them into a single entry and that would also increase performance.

Comment: @Alexey: but your *output* uses ids as unique. So if id A appears twice in your input list, you are processing two sets of numbers and any numbers that appear in both are both going to result in the same output in `processed_data`.

Comment: ok, so you say that  the output should be  a list ? what about the values from "numbers" key? are they unique?

Comment: @rusu_ro1 numbers in ONE list is unique, but you can meet same number in the other 'number' list

Comment: Maybe make your dictionary use the numbers as the key and for each number it can hold a list of the ids which had this number. this will allow for you to append duplicate ids to the list. However you wont be able to tell from teh output which id specifically had the number only that one of the non unique ids had it

Comment: in the output one id can have multiple values? in your example id 0 can have as numbers 3 and 5, your code catch only 5, is there any rule for this?

Comment: @Alexey can you also edit your output? should be like : [{0: [3, 5]}, ... ]

Comment: in the number lists, the lists are unique?

Comment: @rusu_ro1 no, otherwise it will not have any duplicate pairs of numbers

Comment: @Alexey so it is possible to have : [[1,2], [2,9], [4,7] , [1,2], [2,9], [4,7]] ?

Comment: in any case, you can check my solution

Comment: @rusu_ro1 technically yes, but really chanse of this pair is being duplicated in one list is very very tiny, so we could think that there is no duplicating pairs in one 'numbers' list

Comment: how many items do you really have in the input list ?

Comment: @rusu_ro1 105461 dict, every like `{'id' : 0, 'numbers' : [[1,2], [2,9], [4,7], ... ]}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are indeed processing your lists very inefficiently, because you are combining every dictionary with every other dictionary (an O(N^2) order process), then compound this by also combining every value in a list of length K with another list of numbers of similar length with a sequential scan, so you end up with O(N^2 * K^2). That's going to take a long, long time. It's a sequential scan because the containment test you use against your numbers (`number in numbers_list`) has to test every value in the `numbers_list` list one by one until a match is found or the list is exhausted.

You want to learn about [*sets*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). Sets let you test if a number is present in constant time, because each value itself is the key to its location in the data structure, via its hash (so `something in setvalue` just has to see if `hash(something)` exists in the set table). You can also get their intersection very efficiently, so the set of numbers that are present in both sets. For two sets of average size K that takes O(K) linear time. The intersection is simply `setA & setB`.

I'd convert your data structure to contain sets to start with, then for the intersections between two lists record **both** ids per number in the set, because **both** lists have numbers in common. That then lets you reduce the O(N^2) pairing, because when you have tested id A with id B, you don't have to do the same thing for id B against id A. That's technically still O(N^2), but it's really a [triangle number or arithmetic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number); N + N - 1 + N - 2 .... which is (N * (N + 1)) // 2, a decidedly lower number of iterations that for real-world problems is much preferable over full-on N^2; halving the time taken still matters when comparing approaches with real-life situations and finite input sizes.

That looks like this:

```
all = [
    {'id' : 0, 'numbers' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
    {'id' : 1, 'numbers' : [5, 7, 9]},
    {'id' : 2, 'numbers' : [10, 12, 14]},
    {'id' : 3, 'numbers' : [3, 12, 5]},
]
# conversion to sets
for d in all:
    d['numbers'] = set(d['numbers'])

processed_data = {}

for i, entry in enumerate(all):
    id1 = entry['id']
    for j in range(i + 1, len(all)):
        id2 = all[j]['id']
        for num in entry['numbers'] & all[j]['numbers']:
            processed_data.update({id1: num, id2: num})
```

The nested loop can be further simplified by using [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to do the pairing for us:

```
from itertools import combinations

# everything before the loop the same up to setting `processed_data`

for entry1, entry2 in combinations(all, r=2):
    id1, id2 = entry1['id'], entry2['id']
    for num in entry1['numbers'] & entry2['numbers']:
        processed_data.update({id1: num, id2: num})
```

So this halved the number of combinations between the dictionaries you have, and per combination, the work is done in linear time instead of quadratic time. That already could easily drop the processing time to 6 hours, and quite possibly less than that. That's because replacing a O(K^2) algorithm with one that takes O(K) time (with similar fixed costs per step) lets you *divide* the time taken by K. If your lists have a length of 1000 elements, we can expect a 1000-fold decrease in time taken; 3.6 days is about 311000 seconds, so expecting a 3100 second runtime (a little more than 5 hours, and only *very* conservative 100-fold speed-up, not 1000) is not out of the realms of possibilities here. It sounds as if your lists are longer than that, imagine how much faster avoiding the O(K^2) comparisons loops can prove to be!

Next, because your output uses `id` as a unique value, but your *input* in `all` may have multiple entries for a given `id`, you could further *reduce* N and K here by first combining the numbers for each `id` value into a single set. You can do so by mapping `all` to a *dictionary* with `id` as the key, and sets as the values. Because we are still bound by a O(N^2) algorithm to combine the entries in `all`, reducing N can have a big impact; if N = 1000, going to N = 999 removes 1000 set intersections from consideration (replaced by *one* set update to merge the duplicate id first).

Combining the inputs first when converting to sets then becomes:

```
from itertools import combinations

all = [
    {'id' : 0, 'numbers' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
    {'id' : 1, 'numbers' : [5, 7, 9]},
    {'id' : 2, 'numbers' : [10, 12, 14]},
    {'id' : 3, 'numbers' : [3, 12, 5]},
    # I've added another entry with id 1, but different numbers
    {'id' : 1, 'numbers' : [17, 42, 11]},
]
# conversion to sets
all_sets = {}
for d in all:
    all_sets.setdefault(d['id'], set()).update(d['numbers'])

# if memory is an issue at this point, consider adding 'del all'.

processed_data = {}

for (id1, numbers1), (ids2, numbers2) in combinations(all_sets.items(), r=2):
    for num in numbers1 & numbers2:
        processed_data.update({id1: num, id2: num})
```

That double loop is actually simple enough to turn into a dict comprehension; no further advantage other than lowering the fixed cost of executing Python bytecode each step:

```
processed_data = {
    id: num
    for (id1, num1), (ids2, num2) in combinations(all_sets.items(), r=2)
    for num in num1 & num2
    for id in (id1, id2)
}
```

Note that we are only recording the *last* number that is shared with another list for a given `id`. If you wanted to record *all* such numbers, you need to make `processed_data` values lists or sets, so containers that can hold multiple numbers.

You can't then use a dict comprehension. Instead use `dict.setdefault()` to ensure there is an empty container, and add to the container that's returned:

```
processed_data = {}

for (id1, numbers1), (ids2, numbers2) in combinations(all_sets.items(), r=2):
    for num in numbers1 & numbers2:
        processed_data.setdefault(id1, set()).add(num)
        processed_data.setdefault(id2, set()).add(num)
```

This creates sets, but you can also use lists, so `processed_data.setdefault(id1, []).append(num)`, etc. For your sample `all` data, this produces:

```
>>> processed_data
{0: {3, 5}, 3: {3, 5, 12}, 1: {5}, 2: {12}}
```

The above approach requires `numbers` to contain hashable values, which integers are. If your actual setup doesn't have hashable values, *make* them hashable, by converting them for this job. The time savings are *worth the effort*.

E.g. if you have lists of integers that you must find matches for, convert them to tuples first. That is easily done:

```
all_sets = {}
for d in all:
    all_sets.setdefault(d['id'], set()).update(map(tuple, d['numbers']))
```

where `map(tuple, d['numbers'])` applies `tuple()` to each element before adding those tuples to the sets.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I'm asking him right now. Small nit, the code would also look a bit more pythonic using dict `.items()`, `.keys()` and `.values()` instead of enumerating lists items and then accessing the `numbers` field.

Comment: @Adirio: One step at a time :-) I wanted to introduce `itertools.combinations()` in a separate part of the answer (because it can be a bit too magic for people not that versed in math), as well as the dict comprehension I added at the end..

Comment: @MartijnPieters any idea if I have [1,2], [3,4] instead of usual numbers in list? I have such pairs (which I cannot separate, they shoud stay as they are and write as numbers did. I wrote usual numbers for simpliticy, but with such pairs I cannot use `set(d['numbers])`. Please see my edit 2

Comment: @Alexey: then convert them to tuples. I must say that you are constantly moving the goal posts here by altering your requirements. The principles stay the same, once you have converted your mutable values to something that can be hashed. You can always convert back afterwards.

Comment: @Alexey: I've rolled back your last edit. If you have issues adapting my answer to a sequence of mutable values such as nested lists, create a new question. Take into account that several volunteers have put work into answering your original setup now.

Comment: @Alexey: as it is, supporting non-hashable values is easy enough if you can convert the values to something that *is* hashable, so I added a section about that.

Comment: @Alexey: out of curiosity: how long did the task take now? You said it would take you 3.6 days, how long did it take with my updates? :-)

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to pre-process the lists to convert them to sets, that way you can check for set intersections which would likely be much simpler than iterating all the lists a ton. If your numbers are small you could even use bitfields for even faster intersection checking (I guess there's a balance to be had between the size of the lists and the number sets / amount of collisions)

The second is that you don't need to keep checking all the lists: for the first list you can check every other list, but for the second list you don't need to check the first one *again*, 1&2 and 2&1 are the same thing so you already checked the intersection of 2 and 1 when you checked the intersection of 1 and 2. This means the kth list (out of n) only needs to be checked against n-k other lists

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to use Pandas instead of lists and sets.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(all)

dfe = df.explode('numbers')

dfe
   id numbers
0   0       1
0   0       2
0   0       3
0   0       4
0   0       5
1   1       5
1   1       7
1   1       9
2   2      10
2   2      12
2   2      14
3   3       3
3   3      12
3   3       5
```

from there its easy to manipulate duplicates (e.g. see [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method) based on the id and the numbers col. You can also try to combine `.groupby()` and `.duplicated()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try to first exact the data from Python and move it into a more durable storage solution (ie. a database). Since you are talking about a very large volume of data and considering the possibility of spending **days** churning on it, you might set yourself up for success if you spend some time up front pre-processing this data set.

Doing this will also make it easier to re-distribute the data to more than one compute node if you later decide that you need such a solution. On top of that, if you are able to restructure this data to efficiently fit into database tables, you might find that you can re-cast the question as something that is easier to solve using SQL. That has the benefit of essentially letting someone else (again, the database) worry about the details of the implementation, and all you need to do is describe the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

here is an approach where first I count the frequency of all the pair numbers in the input list then I iterate over same input list and I check if the current item has pair numbers with frequency > 1,
if the pair number frequency is > 1 I will append to the processed_data.

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain

all = [
   {'id' : 0, 'numbers' : [[1,2], [2,9], [4,7]]},
   {'id' : 1, 'numbers' : [[8,2],  [2,9], [3,3]]},
   {'id' : 2, 'numbers' : [[6,6], [1,2], [8,8]]},
   {'id' : 3, 'numbers' : [[7,2], [8,1], [1,9]]}
]

# use tuple for pair numbers, needed for Counter, lists are not hashable
all = [{'id': e['id'], 'numbers': [tuple(l) for l in e['numbers']]} for e in all]

full_counter = Counter(chain(*map(itemgetter('numbers'), all)))

def get_nums_in_other(l):
    counter = Counter(l)
    return [e for e in counter if counter[e] < full_counter[e]]

processed_data = {i['id']: get_nums_in_other(i['numbers'])  for i in all}

# transform tuples in lists
processed_data = {k: [list(e) for e in v] for k, v in processed_data.items() if v}
processed_data
```

output:

```
{0: [[1, 2], [2, 9]], 1: [[2, 9]], 2: [[1, 2]]}
```

to avoid iterating 1 time over `all` and one time over `processed_data`(when tuples are transforming to lists) you can use a `for` loop:

```
def get_nums_in_other(l):
    counter = Counter(l)
    return [list(e) for e in counter if counter[e] < full_counter[e]]

processed_data = {}

for item in all:
    nums_in_other = get_nums_in_other(item['numbers'])
    if nums_in_other:
        processed_data[item['id']] = nums_in_other
processed_data
```